# JavaScript: why is boolean always returning true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

When I run this with any value for customerNumber, it always returns the first alert message in the if statement. What is wrong here?

```
var customerNumbers = 13;
var winningNumbers = [];
winningNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);
var match = false;
for (i=0; i<winningNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (winningNumbers[i] == customerNumbers) {
        match = true;
    }
}
if (match = true) {
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + winningNumbers.toString() + 
    "\nThe Customer's Number is:\n" + customerNumbers + "\nWe have a match and a winner!");
}
else {
    alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + winningNumbers.toString() + 
    "\nThe Customer's Number is:\n" + customerNumbers + "\nSorry, you are not a winner this week.");
}
```

Comment: `if (match = true)` --> `if (match === true) ` It should just be `if (match)`, though.

Comment: Oops! So simple, thanks!

Comment: Should really just be `if (match) {` - since you've created a boolean value, just use it directly. No comparison is necessary.

Comment: You should delete this question before you get downvotes and answer... well, wait... Never mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing the boolean `match` to `true` your are assigning `true` to the boolean `match`. You need to use a double or triple =.

```
match = true // Sets match to true
match == true // Compares match to true
match === true // Strictly compares match to true
```

So add some more equal signs and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the assignment operator(`=`) in the if statement. Use the equality operator (`===`).

`if (match === true)`